# Writing a getBulkRequest function using SNMPv2 and c++

Tags: c++, qt, format, snmp

I am writing a getBulkRequest function which is supposed to allow me to request for a list of information at one go.

For now, I would like to do something simple, using the GetBulkRequest to just sequentially getNextRequest by setting the "Non-Repetition" to "0" in getBulkRequest.

- **Am I writing the format correctly?**
- **For the Oid, do I only need to input ONE Oid(the first item of the Bulk)?**
- **If I wish to get a bulk request starting from the stated Oid, and the following 4 items after the first, do I simply set the "Max-Repetition" to 5?**

This is the format that I am using, could anyone advise me on whether I am doing it right or not:

```
switch(pdyType) {
 case PdyType::GET_BULK_REQUEST:
for (QStringList::ConstIterator iter = oids.begin(); iter != oids.end(); ++iter)
{

  QByteArray keyHolder;

  //value
  keyHolder.push_front(QByteArray(1, 0x00));
  keyHolder.push_front(QByteArray(1, DataType::DATA_NULL));

  //object identifier
  QByteArray temp = encodeoid(*iter);
  keyHolder.push_front(temp);
  keyHolder.push_front(encodeLengthField(temp.size()));
  keyHolder.push_front(QByteArray(1, DataType::OBJECT_ID));

  //varbind
  keyHolder.push_front(encodeLengthField(keyHolder.size()));
  keyHolder.push_front(QByteArray(1, DataType::SEQUENCE));

  datagram.push_front(keyHolder);
}

//max-repetitions
datagram.push_front(QByteArray(1, 5);
datagram.push_front(QByteArray(1, 1);
datagram.push_front(QByteArray(1, DataType::INTEGER);

//varbind list
datagram.push_front(QByteArray(encodeLengthField(datagram.size());
datagram.push_front(QByteArray(1, DataType::SEQUENCE);

//non-repeaters
datagram.push_front(QByteArray(1, 0);
datagram.push_front(QByteArray(1, 1);
datagram.push_front(QByteArray(1, DataType::INTEGER);

//requestId
datagram.push_front(QByteArray(1, requestId));
datagram.push_front(QByteArray(1, 1);
datagram.push_front(QByteArray(1, DataType::INTEGER);

//pdu
datagram.push_front(QByteArray(encodeLengthField(datagram.size()));
datagram.push_front(QByteArray(1, (unsigned char)pduType);

//community string
datagram.push_front(QByteArray(community.toLocal8Bit()));
datagram.push_front(QByteArray(encodeLengthField(community.size());
datagram.push_front(QByteArray(1, DataType::OCTET_STRING);

//version
datagram.push_front(QByteArray(1, 0));
datagram.push_front(QByteArray(1, 1);
datagram.push_front(QByteArray(1, DataType::INTEGER);

//message type
datagram.push_front(QByteArray(encodeLengthField(datagram.size()));
datagram.push_front(QByteArray(1, DataType::SEQUENCE);
break;


default:
 break;
 }
 return datagram;
```

Is the format correct for getBulkRequest to be set out via QUdpSocket::writeDatagram?

I hope I am able to phrase my issue clearly. As I am not very sure what is going on at the moment and trying to read up more.

Comment: Any advice/suggestions? Help needed.

Answer (score 0):

Q: For the Oid, do I only need to input ONE Oid(the first item of the Bulk)?

A: Yes, you only need to set the first OID.

Q: If I wish to get a bulk request starting from the stated Oid, and the following 4 items after the first, do I simply set the "Max-Repetition" to 5?

A: Yes. 5 is the minimum that you need to set for max-repetition, but you can set to a bigger value (e.g. 10). The way you would work with the response is to traverse over the response PDU and get out each OID at a time.

Hope this help.